# output.json e app-relase.apk no Android Studio e da erro ao instalar

Tags: android, json, android-studio, apk

Ola, bom dia!

Toda vez que baixo algum exemplo de projeto no AS, percebo que se ao gerar o apk vier junto o output.json, o app nao instala de forma alguma (seja no emulador ou no aparelho)

Ja vi varias resposta de que é pra ignorar esse .json, mas é certo, toda vez que baixo um projeto e gera isso o app nao instala.

exemplo:
https://github.com/ofuwape/FlickrFindr

Mudei apenas o APIKEY do Flickr e ao gerar o o apk veio junto o output.json.

Queria saber se tem como resolver isso;

Uso o Android Studio 3.2.1

Obg!

Answer (score 0):

O Android Studio 3.0 + é responsável por este arquivo. Você não precisa se preocupar com o `output.json`, ele apenas trás informações sobre o APK gerado.

Olhe bem:

Para versões mais antigas, o que o Android Studio fez foi gerar um APK assinado e colocá-lo na pasta "output". 
É apenas mostrando as diferentes propriedades do APK gerado.

A partir do Android Studio 3.0 +, eles organizaram essa estrutura de arquivos. Para cada assinatura de um APK, o APK sempre irá acompanhado com um arquivo `output.json` correspondente. Este arquivo é, na verdade, nada além de uma descrição do APK de origem gerado.

Agora, sobre dar falha na instalação, veja no `logcat` qual erro está gerando, e poste para que possamos lhe ajudar.